# Most of the log missing after using AsyncWrapper at NLog

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, logging, nlog

I was using **NLog** **synchronous** logging that wrote all of my log messages but that took more time to execute. So, I looked forward to **asynchronous** log. But after implement async logging many logs are missing when per second log is more than **300**. But my requirement is to write more than **2000** log in a second.

I am using this below NLog config :

```
  <targets>
    <target name="asyncViewer" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" overflowAction="Block" queueLimit="1000000" batchSize="1000" timeToSleepBetweenBatches="0">
      <target xsi:type="Chainsaw" name="viewer" address="udp://127.0.0.1:9999">
        <parameter name="exception" layout="${exception:format=Type,Message,StackTrace:separator=&#13;&#10;}" />
      </target>
    </target>

  </targets>
```

How could I fix this? 
Give me any kind of suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any warnings or errors when enabling the internal logger -> https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging ??

Comment: no warnings or errors shown.

Comment: You have excluded the logging-rules from the question, could you add those? Remember all of them has to be mapped to asyncViewer-target instead of the wrapped viewer-target.

Comment: What version of NLog are you using?

Comment: Have you tried to lower the `batchSize` of the asyncViewer-target to 10 or 50 ? (Or maybe just 1 for testing)

Answer (score 0):

What logviewer-application are you using to view the output from Chainsaw-target? Have you tried to use TCP instead of UDP?

Maybe the logviewer-application is not able to handle the UDP-packages, and needs some help to split the LogEvents by adding `newline="true"`:

```
  <targets>
    <target name="asyncViewer" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" overflowAction="Block" queueLimit="1000000" batchSize="1000" timeToSleepBetweenBatches="0">
      <target xsi:type="Chainsaw" name="viewer" address="udp://127.0.0.1:9999" newline="true">
        <parameter name="exception" layout="${exception:format=Type,Message,StackTrace:separator=&#13;&#10;}" />
      </target>
    </target>
  </targets>
```

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2145